# Getting sales data for data mining

Tags: data-mining

I am working on a data mining project that requires massive sales data of retail stores.
Is such kind of data available online? I tried to Google but all I got was some really sketchy datasets.

Any help will be appreciated ..

Answer (score 0):

It might be quite difficult to find, because most companies consider this information highly secret for competitive reasons.

One possibility is look at similar industries which actually publish large amounts of sales information - for example you can get quite detailed box office takings for cinemas, or gate reciepts for sporting events etc.

If you've got some cash to spare, one company that sells a frankly quite scary amount of information is ebay:

- http://developer.ebay.com/programs/marketdata/

Answer (score 0):

You may find something interesting in the links below:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/, http://deeplearning.net/datasets/, http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/.

Answer (score -1):

Someone already suggested http://www.kdnuggets.com/datasets/ , which is a great source of data. Among the options is the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/), a great resource for freely available datasets.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That same person also linked (in 2013) to UCI, too. Making your answer 100% redundant.